# discord.py: How to delete a value out of a json file?

Tags: python, discord.py

My code:

```
@bot.command()
async def delwarn(ctx, member: discord.Member = None, warnid = None):
    if member:

          with open('warns.json', 'r') as fcheckifthere:
                checkifthere = json.load(fcheckifthere)
          if f'{member.id}' in checkifthere.keys():

                amount = len(checkifthere[f'{member.id}'])
                if f'{warnid}' in checkifthere[f'{member.id}']:
                    if not amount == 1:
                        
# i want to delete the value f"{warnid}"   
                         del checkifthere[f'{member.id}'][f'{warnid}']
                          with open('warns.json', 'w+') as fcheckifthere:
                              json.dump(checkifthere, fcheckifthere, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I want to delete the specific value f"{warnid}", but I don't know how and I get this error.

Here is an example how the json file looks like:

```
{
   305354423801217025: [
      0145324124,
      2142141244
   ]
{
```

Comment: Could you share your json file or an example of how a warn is stored in it?

Comment: yes. I edited the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in this line, where you try to delete the warn ID:

```py
del checkifthere[f'{member.id}'][f'{warnid}']
```

`checkifthere[f'{member.id}']` is a list and the index you're giving is a string. List indeces must be integer so you have an error.
The simplest way to delete list elements is to use `list.remove(element)`:

```py
checkifthere[str(member.id)].remove(warnid)
```

Also, you don't need `f strings`, you can use `str()` to convert integers and floats to strings.

---

With a bit of refactoring, here's how your command would look like:

```
from discord import Member
from discord.ext import commands
from json import load, dump

@bot.command()
async def delwarn(ctx, member: Member = None, warn_id: str = None):
    if not member:
        return
    with open('warns.json', 'r') as file:
        data = load(file)
        member_id = str(member.id)
    if not member_id in data.keys():
        return
    if warn_id in data[member_id] and not len(data[member_id]) == 1:
        with open('warns.json', 'w') as file:
            data[member_id].remove(warn_id)
            dump(data, file, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```